# Does capistrano deploy only the last commit or all the commits in order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano

Wrote a nasty migration, committed and then removed the file and committed again.

If I deploy will it process the file or not?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capistrano deploys the state of your git repository as of the latest commit in the branch you are deploying. If you added a file and then later removed it, then no, it will not be included when you deploy.